# Can't connect to Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I tried the default id and password neo4j to log in but failed,
I also delete the auth file as the instructions online told, but nothing changed,
is there anyway to reset the password WITHOUT LOG IN ?

Comment: Are you using Neo4j Browser?

Comment: Yes, I am tring to log in both on the Neo4j Browser and the Chrome, but all failed to input password

Answer (score 0):

You can reset the DBMS password in the Neo4j browser. By just selecting the DBMS[image]

You will get an option to reset your password on the right-side panel.
If this doesn't work, and you just want to work locally, you can disable the authentication itself, by going to the DBMS settings, by clicking on `...`, and `Settings`. Then set the property `dbms.security.auth_enabled` to `false`.

[image]

Note: Disabling authentication is not recommended for any sort of workplace development environment.